# String or characters are turning to numbers while running split and as in r

Tags: r, string, split

I am splitting a transaction file (data) which has SKU and Transaction IDs. I want to use this file for market basket analysis using arules library.

The issue is as follows:
data

```
sku transactionId
GSB 1000019214173610000
HF  1000035644171470000
MT  1000035644171470000
WP  1000035644171470000
ED  1000043731010500000
DT  1000044672723070000
DT  1000118604897040000
CF  1000118604897040000
VS  1000165528585840000
```

I run:

```
isplit <- split(data$sku, data$transactionId)
trn <- as(isplit, "transactions")
```

When i inspect the output of trn, all the SKU values are converted to integers instead of their own names like following:

```
{54}    1000019214173610000
{23,35,108} 1000035644171470000
{66}    1000043731010500000
{23}    1000044672723070000
{23}    1000118604897040000
{27}    1000044672723070000
```

Any idea why am I losing the SKU values?

Comment: Wild guess: `data$sku` is a factor.  Try wrapping it with `as.character()` in `split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Richard Scriven ,

I wrapped data$sku with as.character() in split.

updated code:

```
isplit <- split(as.character(data$sku), data$transactionId)
```